# etoolbox bool statement always chooses second option

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, revtex

I am trying to set up a bool in my bibliography to select whether or not to abbreviate journal titles. As a minimal example consider this bib file:

```
\newbool{abbrv}
\setbool{abbrv}{false}

\ifbool{abbrv}{@string{PRL="Phys. Rev. Lett."}}{@string{PRL="Physical Review Letters"}}

@article{person2022something,
    author = {Person, Person},
    journal = PRL,
    number = {1},
    pages = {100},
    publisher = {APS},
    title = {Something something},
    volume = {123},
    year = {2022}
}
```

My theory is that I can set abbrv to choose whether or not to abbreviate the journals. The problem is that no matter what, the second option is always chosen, i.e PRL="Physical Review Letters" no matter if abbrv is true or false.

I should point out that I am using overleaf and revtex. My preamble preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl,superscriptaddress,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
```

Am I using the etools bool incorrectly? Or is something else causing it to fail?

Comment: Can you use TeX code like that in a .bib file? I don't think so. That code is simply ignored because only `@` triggers reading.

Comment: I know I can set @string{prl='something} in the bib file, but yes, maybe I cant use the etoolbox in the bib file. Is there a way to define that in the tex document?

Comment: create two bib files,  one with the @string for abbreviations and one with the other. Then you can load them conditionally in your document.

Comment: you can't use _any_  tex constructs in the bib file, this is not specific to etoolbox booleans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the choice inside `@string` and define and set the boolean in the `@preamble` section of your `.bib` file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{"\newbool{abbrv}\setbool{abbrv}{true}"}
@string{PRL="\ifbool{abbrv}{Phys. Rev. Let.}{Physical Review Letters}"}

@article{person2022something,
    author = {Person, Person},
    journal = PRL,
    number = {1},
    pages = {100},
    publisher = {APS},
    title = {Something something},
    volume = {123},
    year = {2022}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[reprint,aps,prl,superscriptaddress,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\begin{document}
\cite{person2022something}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this would cause the bib file to fail if it is used in another document that does not load `etoolbox`. This can be avoided by using built-in LaTeX conditionals:

```
@preamble{"\newif\ifabbrv\abbrvtrue"}
@string{PRL="\ifabbrv Phys. Rev. Let.\else Physical Review Letters\fi"}
```

You can set the boolean to true with `\abbrvtrue` (as above) and to false with `\abbrvfalse`.